# Show subtasks(related to the task) in Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Sorry if the title was confusing, I'm creating a web application which lets the user to add tasks and sub-tasks.I have managed to make angular to get the tasks from database(mongodb) and show the result in my dashboard.html file. But I'm having problems with the sub-tasks. I have a button on each task and when clicked should show all the sub-tasks which belong to that task. In the current situation the problem is that when I want to see the sub-tasks belonging to one task they appear as sub-tasks of all of my tasks.

My `dashboard.html` looks like this:

```
<body ng-app="dashboard">
    <div class="container list-group list-group"  ng-controller="dashboardCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="task in tasks" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <li class="list_style">
                <span>{{task.name}}</span><span>{{task.description}}</span>
                <span><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(task._id)">Delete</button></span>
                <span><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="edit(task._id)">Edit</button></span>
                <span><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addTask(task._id)">Add new task</button></span>
                <span><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="showTasks(task._id)">+</button></span>
            </li>
            <ul ng-repeat="subTask in subTasks" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" 
                style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <li>{{subTask.name}}</li>
                    <li>{{subTask.description}}</li>
                    <li>{{subTask.due_date}}</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>    
    </div>
</body>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('dashboard', []);
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window){

    ///////Used to get all the tasks from the database

     var refresh = function() {
        $http.get('api/tasks').then(function(response) {
          $scope.tasks = response.data;
          console.log("Data retrieved successfully");
          console.log(response);
        });
      };
      refresh();

      ///////Used to get the all the sub-tasks belonging to task with specified id

      $scope.showsubTasks = function(id){
        $http.get('api/task/'+ id).then(function(response) {
            console.log("Data retrieved successfully");
            console.log(response);
            $scope.subTasks = response.data.subTasks;
          });
      }  
})
```

And my task schema looks like this:

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose");

const taskSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    } ,
     subTasks:[{
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        description:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        due_date:{
            type: String,
            required:true
        }
     }]
});
const list = module.exports = mongoose.model("list", listSchema);
```

The index.js file:

```
///// to get the tasks
router.get("/tasks", (req,res)=>{
    task.find((err, lists)=>{
        res.json(tasks);
    })

});

////// to get the sub-tasks from a task with specified id

router.get("/task/:id", (req,res)=>{
    task.findOne({_id:req.params.id},'sub_tasks',(err, sub_tasks)=>{
        res.json(sub_tasks);
    })

});
```

I believe the problem is on: `$scope.subTasks = response.data.subTasks;` since subTasks is the array from which the sub-tasks derive or where all the sub-tasks are pushed when we get them from the database but I'm finding it impossible to find a solution right now. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this problem is related to mongodb... as you know where is the problem

Comment: @Ashish I do not think too, I think the problem is how I'm saving and getting the data from $scope.subTasks, since all the subtasks receive data from it, so if it holds some subtasks, all the tasks are getting the same subtasks.

Comment: you haven't posted any query... you just posted a schema which will not help at all to answer your question

Comment: I added two queries in the answer.

Comment: try this `res.json({data: tasks})` and `res.json({ data: sub_tasks })
`

Comment: The queries work fine, I'm getting the needed data, I'm getting all the sub-tasks from a specific list, but I'm having problems applying that with angular, I mean showing all the sub-tasks underneath each belonging task. Like, if task 1 has 2 sub-task, there need to be these 2 sub-tasks underneath it, if task 2 has 5 sub-tasks, these 5 sub-tasks should appear underneath task 2.

Comment: I have heard about the populate, but never actually tried it, could you please show me an example?

Comment: Don't know what your second query `findone` does??

Comment: It finds only one document based on the condition. In this case it finds a document with an id the same as the id in the url parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you should create the sub tasks inside the li and not in the ul.

you code looks like that:

```
<ul ng-repeat="task in tasks" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <li class="list_style">
            <span>{{task.name}}</span><span>{{task.description}}</span>
            <span><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(task._id)">Delete</button></span>
            <span><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="edit(task._id)">Edit</button></span>
            <span><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addTask(task._id)">Add new task</button></span>
            <span><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="showTasks(task._id)">+</button></span>
        </li>
        <ul ng-repeat="subTask in subTasks" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" 
            style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <li>{{subTask.name}}</li>
                <li>{{subTask.description}}</li>
                <li>{{subTask.due_date}}</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

and you should change it to:

```
<ul ng-repeat="task in tasks" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <li class="list_style">
            <span>{{task.name}}</span><span>{{task.description}}</span>
            <span><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(task._id)">Delete</button></span>
            <span><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="edit(task._id)">Edit</button></span>
            <span><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addTask(task._id)">Add new task</button></span>
            <span><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="showTasks(task._id)">+</button></span>
        </li>
        <li>
        <ul class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" 
            style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <li ng-repeat="subTask in task.subTasks">
                {{subTask.name}}
                {{subTask.description}}
                {{subTask.due_date}}
                </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

you can send attribute of angularjs that called: `$index` it will give you the current index that the task related to and send it also to function
and after you get the response for subTasks you should attach it to correct task like that:

```
$scope.tasks[i].subTasks = response.data;
```

Comment: Sorry but that didn't change the result, as I said before I think the problem is how I'm saving and getting the data from $scope.subTasks, since all the subtasks receive data from it, so if it holds some subtasks, all the tasks are getting the same subtasks

Comment: Can you do a console.log(response) with the response from the server?

Comment: I have already done it, the refresh method works correctly, the showsubTasks returns all the sub-task  which are inside the id-specified task.

Comment: After you getting back the subTasks, you need to search the index that the task is exists, or you can just send a default paramter of angularjs that called $index and then do this line: $scope.tasks[i].subTask = response.data. in the Html you should do this line in the ng-repeat: subTask in task.subTasks and that way you have the subTasks that related to task

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the subTask objects, in form of an array, but they're not appearing under the correct task, they're appearing under all tasks. Lets say the last task has 3 subtasks, then those 3 subtasks are appearing under all the other tasks instead of only the last task. I'll try your method, thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check it and see if it fix the issue.

Comment: You do not know what kind of good deed you've done to me! Thanks very much. Just had to change `subTask in subTasks` with `subTask in task.subTasks`.

Comment: Glad to help ;)